# ajaxSubmit() OnProgress not working on first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Sorry, if not understandable on some points, I'm trying my best:

I'm trying to fix my little AJAX bug, which contains a file upload with ajaxSubmit. I want to show a progressbar but when first clicking on the submit button, the OnProgress event does not work, although the consolelog shows the percentage of the completion.
After the first upload, I'm choosing another file WITHOUT refreshing the page. From this time on, the progressbar works perfectly.

What problem does cause the OnProgress event not to start on the first time?

HTML:

```
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo URL; ?>album/uploadImage/<?php echo $this->album->id; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_upload">
                <input id="imgUpload" name="file_upload" type="file" required />
                <div class="progress success radius">
                <span class="meter"></span>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Bild hochladen" id="submitupload" />
            </form>
```

jQuery, in connection with the [jQuery Form plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/form/): (Please check the comments on the function OnProgress!)

```
var progressbar     = $('.meter');
var completed       = '0%';

var options = { 
    target: 'body',
    beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
    uploadProgress: OnProgress,
    success: afterSuccess,
    resetForm: true
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#form_upload').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);    
        return false; // Verhindert das Neuladen der Seite!
    });
});

function OnProgress(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    console.log("OnProgress called: " + percentComplete + "%");
    progressbar.width(percentComplete + "%"); 
    // This line is only working AFTER the first time. 
    // When clicking on the submit button the first time, 
    // the progressbar does not increase.
}

function afterSuccess() {
    console.log("AfterSuccess called.");
}

function beforeSubmit() {
    console.log("BeforeSubmit called.");
}
```

In addition after the first time I uploaded a picture, other jQuery initializations are not working anymore. I'm using the Foundation 5 Framework and initialize it with

```
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

But after the first picture, some events like the [Alert-Box closing link](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html) are not working anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days, I found the problem.

```
var progressbar     = $('.meter');
var completed       = '0%';
```

both were not loaded, this means, they're not in the

```
$(document).ready(function () { ... });
```

bracket.

So the progressbar and the value of "completed" were initialized on the second upload, when the body was refreshed.

This also solved the problem with the success alert-box, which showed up after the upload. Finally, I can close the alert-box with a simple click on its cross.